# Preparedstatement Parameters for "SELECT ... WHERE para1 OR para2" , How?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Could someone explain the correct way, How can we pass the parameters when use a query with (WHERE) "OR"?

```
"SELECT ... WHERE paraX=? OR paraY=?";
```

I'm trying with below codes, but them isn't execute.

```
pstm.setString(1, 1st_para);
pstm.setString(2, 2nd_para);
```

(Please note I'm a very beginner for JAVA and Preparedstatement)

Thanx!

Comment: Looks fine. Other than you didn't actually execute any query. Is there any error? http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: can you please provide the issue that you are facing?

Comment: For clarification, `pstm.executeQuery()` needs called somewhere. Please show a [mcve] of your code with an [edit] to the question

Comment: The most frequent error seems to be `pstm.executeQuery("...")` instead of the parameterless `executeQuery()`.

Comment: As an part of example code below, am I correct or wrong (meaned passed 2 parameters?) 
    "SELECT stud_id FROM table_student WHERE city=? OR country=?";
    pstm.setString(1, "Texas");
    pstm.setString(2, "USA");

Comment: See the [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

As you are beginner in Java, have a look at the following code, DB tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `salary` DECIMAL NULL,
  `age` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`));

INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `salary`, `age`) VALUES ('Abc', '100.23', '23');
INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `salary`, `age`) VALUES ('Def', '220.2', '34');
INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `salary`, `age`) VALUES ('Pqr', '50.44', '12');
INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `salary`, `age`) VALUES ('Xyz', '75.66', '20');
INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_name`, `salary`, `age`) VALUES ('Lmn', '150.0', '30');
```

Get the mysql-connector-java dependendency (use Maven, or include it in classpath). Codebase:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PreparedStatementDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.err.println("No driver found..");
    }

    try {
      Connection conn =
          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://${host}:${port}/${dbname}", "${username}", "${password}");

      PreparedStatement prepareStatement =
          conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary > ? AND age > ?");
      prepareStatement.setDouble(1, 75.0);
      prepareStatement.setInt(2, 20);

      ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery();

      int i = 1;
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("Row: " + i);
        System.out.println("\tId: " + resultSet.getInt(1));
        System.out.println("\tName: " + resultSet.getString(2));
        System.out.println("\tSalary: " + resultSet.getDouble(3));
        System.out.println("\tAge: " + resultSet.getInt(4));
        i++;
      }

      prepareStatement.close();
      conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println("Error in DB communication: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Edit the values of the connection string.
PreparedStatement accepts run-time values with index beginning from 1.
Same is the case with ResultSet.

Comment: With your code if I execute a query to get salary OR age, how many prepareStatements I have to pass?
conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary > ? OR age > ?");
      prepareStatement.setDouble(1, 75.0);
      prepareStatement.setInt(2, 20);

Comment: As an part of example code below, am I correct or wrong (meaned passed 2 parameters?)     "SELECT stud_id FROM table_student WHERE city=? OR country=?";     pstm.setString(1, "Texas");     pstm.setString(2, "USA");

Comment: "how many prepareStatements I have to pass?", I didn't get the question. Are you asking about the number of parameters? [This will be number of '?' in the query. Relational operators (OR, AND, NOT) doesn't have to do anything with this]

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT ... WHERE paraX=? OR paraY=?";
pstm.setString(1, "1st_Text");
pstm.setString(2, "2nd_Text");
```

I have found the problem, an error has occurred with my coding mistake. 'Cos I had called the method in ActionForforme of TextArea. But have to call it in the KeyReleased Area.  So, the code is correct. Why I haven't mentioned the code before, 'Cos this is only a method yet I haven't finished the coding..

Thanks all for your valuable time you have wasted for my question..

```
public static void FillAttendsTable(JTable table, String valueToSearch) throws Exception {

    clasid = jTextField_Class_ID.getText();
    studid = jTextField_Stud_ID.getText();

    if((!clasid.equals("") && studid.equals("")) || (clasid.equals("") && !studid.equals(""))){

        cs = " AND (cs.clas_id = ? OR cs.stud_id = ?)";

    }else if(!clasid.equals("") && !studid.equals("")){

        cs = " AND cs.clas_id = ? AND s.stud_id = ?";

    }else if(clasid.equals("") && studid.equals("")){

        cs = " AND CONCAT(c.clas_gred,clas_stat,clas_end,c.note,stud_fnem)LIKE ?";
    }

    Connection conc = Config.DBConnector.getConnection();

    if(jCheckBox_Present.isSelected() && (!clasid.equals("") || !studid.equals(""))){
        qri = "SELECT DISTINCT cs.clas_id,c.clas_gred,s.stud_id,stud_fnem,stud_lnem,a.atn_date,clas_stat,clas_end FROM (((tbl_clas_stud AS cs JOIN tbl_student As s ON cs.stud_id = s.stud_id) JOIN tbl_class AS c ON cs.clas_id = c.clas_id) JOIN tbl_attends AS a ON a.clas_id=cs.clas_id) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.stud_id FROM tbl_attends AS a WHERE cs.stud_id=a.stud_id)"+cs;
    num = "1";

    pstm = (PreparedStatement) conc.prepareStatement(qri);
    pstm.setString(1, clasid);
    pstm.setString(2, studid);

    }else if(jCheckBox_Absent.isSelected() && (!clasid.equals("") || !studid.equals(""))){
        qri = "SELECT DISTINCT cs.clas_id,c.clas_gred,s.stud_id,stud_fnem,stud_lnem,a.atn_date,clas_stat,clas_end FROM (((tbl_clas_stud AS cs JOIN tbl_student As s ON cs.stud_id = s.stud_id) JOIN tbl_class AS c ON cs.clas_id = c.clas_id) JOIN tbl_attends AS a ON a.clas_id=cs.clas_id) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.stud_id FROM tbl_attends AS a WHERE cs.stud_id=a.stud_id)"+cs;
    num = "0";

    pstm = (PreparedStatement) conc.prepareStatement(qri);
    pstm.setString(1, clasid);
    pstm.setString(2, studid);

    }else if(jCheckBox_Absent.isSelected()) {
        qri = "SELECT DISTINCT cs.clas_id,c.clas_gred,s.stud_id,stud_fnem,stud_lnem,a.atn_date,clas_stat,clas_end FROM (((tbl_clas_stud AS cs JOIN tbl_student As s ON cs.stud_id = s.stud_id) JOIN tbl_class AS c ON cs.clas_id = c.clas_id) JOIN tbl_attends AS a ON a.clas_id=cs.clas_id) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.stud_id FROM tbl_attends AS a WHERE cs.stud_id=a.stud_id)"+cs; 
    num = "0";

    pstm = (PreparedStatement) conc.prepareStatement(qri);
    pstm.setString(1, "%" + valueToSearch + "%");

    }else if(jCheckBox_Present.isSelected()) {
        qri = "SELECT DISTINCT cs.clas_id,c.clas_gred,s.stud_id,stud_fnem,stud_lnem,a.atn_date,clas_stat,clas_end FROM (((tbl_clas_stud AS cs JOIN tbl_student As s ON cs.stud_id = s.stud_id) JOIN tbl_class AS c ON cs.clas_id = c.clas_id) JOIN tbl_attends AS a ON a.clas_id=cs.clas_id) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.stud_id FROM tbl_attends AS a WHERE cs.stud_id=a.stud_id)"+cs;
    num = "1";

    pstm = (PreparedStatement) conc.prepareStatement(qri);
    pstm.setString(1, "%" + valueToSearch + "%");

    }

    ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    dtm.setRowCount(0);

    Object[] row;

    while (rs.next()) {
        row = new Object[9];
        row[0] = rs.getString(1);
        row[1] = rs.getString(2);
        row[2] = rs.getString(3);
        row[3] = rs.getString(4);
        row[4] = rs.getString(5);
        row[5] = rs.getString(6);
        row[6] = rs.getString(7);
        row[7] = rs.getString(8);
        row[8] = num;

        dtm.addRow(row);
    }
}
```